# My SQL UPDATE query in ASP.net Isnt working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
var session_username = Session["user"];
string sql1 = "UPDATE Users SET email='" + newemail.Text + "' WHERE username = '" + session_username + "'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Response.Write("alert('DATA UPDATED')");
```

i am getting the message where it is stating the data has been updated. however there are no errors on the page. can someone please help

Comment: What is the value of session_username getting passed? it may be that 0 rows are getting updated.

Comment: Yeah. make am inimum sample. Remove anything that is irrelevant. Like ASP..NET - this is the same for a command line app. You have a trivial problem updating data that you try to bury in a badly formulated question. How you know that the data has not been updated?

Comment: First you dispose of cmd and then you try to execute it.

Comment: Either log your `sql1` string to see what the actual query is or run in a debugger so you can inspect that value....and why would you dispose the command before execution?

Comment: Now you have removed the cmd.dispose() line. Do you still get the same behaviour? If yes, then you need to provide a lot more details.

Comment: @shadow yes i am still getting the same error. I've also tried taking out the where clause, but still same problem. this code is inserted into a button where its executed by the press of  a button

Comment: Pretty pretty please : listen to what Zohar said about parameters; your code is **horribly** open to abuse - SQL injection is both trivial and prevalent

Comment: What is the error you are getting? It looks like you should receive a response of "DATA UPDATED" no matter what happens unless something goes horribly wrong and the program bombs before it gets there.

Comment: i am  getting no errors. its just not updating the field in the database

Answer (score 3):

First, **Always** use parameterized queries, otherwise you are risking [Sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Second, your `cmd.Dispose();` is called before your `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`. You should get an exception.

Third, you shouldn't call `Dispose()` yourself, you should wrap any [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) object in a [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement.

Your code should look more like this:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    var session_username = Session["user"];
    string sql1 = "UPDATE Users SET email= @email WHERE username = @UserName";
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = newemail.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = session_username ;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("alert('DATA UPDATED')");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well said, especially on the parameters. The only thing I can add would be an "or even easier with dapper": `conn.Execute("UPDATE Users SET email= @email WHERE username = @UserName", new { email = newemail.Text, UserName = Session["user"] });`

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks!